# I am really struggling with this join in 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to get to the bottom of this query.

I really am stumped.
I am using my Joins wrong and I cant figure it out, maybe my structure is also wrong.

I need to get a whole lot more records back from the `naedo` table.

1. `account_details` is the main(parent) table and also contains the categories in which the data will apear (in the Grid below Blue=mfin and green=emprica)
2. `paysoft_results` holds all the payment info ('Successful', Unsuccessful, Tracking, Dispute)
   Im only intrested in 'Successful'
3. NAEDO table contains payments that should have taken place (except for the odd double entry which DISTINCT takes care of)

Now Im not getting nearly enough returns from NAEDO and the team lead said Im on the right track but do I understand joins? So I assume there is where the problem lies possibly.

```
  select 
    ad.EMPIRICA,
    ad.MFIN,
    sum(n.cnt) as NAEDO,
    sum(ps.cnt) as paySoft,
    round(sum(ps.cnt) / sum(n.cnt) * 100,1) as percent
  from 
  (
    select 
      account_no,
      to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 5, '9999') || '-' || to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 14, '9999') as EMPIRICA,
      to_char(trunc((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1, 'fm000') || '-' || to_char(trunc((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 25, 'fm000') as MFIN
    from account_details
  ) ad
  left join 
  (
    select custno, count(*) as cnt
    from paysoft_results 
    where result = 'Successful' 
    and resultdate >= cast(date_trunc('month', (current_date- interval '1 month')) as date)+12
    and resultdate <= cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date) + 11
    group by custno
  ) ps on ps.custno = ad.account_no
  right outer join 
  (
    select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
    from naedo 
    where start_date >= cast(date_trunc('month', (current_date- interval '1 month')) as date)+12
    and start_date <= cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date) + 11
    group by customer_code
  ) n on n.customer_code = ad.account_no 
  group by ad.EMPIRICA, ad.MFIN
  order by ad.EMPIRICA, ad.MFIN;
```

**SOME EXTRA RELATED INFO FROM A PREVIOUS QUESTION**

Relationship

[image]

The data will be presented on a grid. with
 `[account_detail]empirica_score` as the row titles
and
 `[account_detail]mfin_score` as the column titles

like this (will explane the 99% in a second)
[image]

`account_details` the first sub select. is just for catagories.
The query needs to get the `epirica_score` and `mfin_score` to determinate the placement on the grid (e.g. where the 99% is)

Get `distinct` values for `[NAEDO]startdate` where keys match.
more or less like this

1. So you get the 2 scores to determinate the placement.
2. amount of (paysoft_result / NAEDO) * 100 = `grid value`
3. calculation need to be per customer. and the grand totals put in the grid.

I have no clue how to tackle a query like this. its for a jasper report.

any ideas?

here is some (hopefully) usefull data

**account_details table**

```
account_no    title    surname    firstname    empirica_score    mfin_score   
1000002222    "Mr"    "Petersen"    "Andrew peter"    602    97
1000002828    "Mr"    "Mars"    "Abraham"    599    97
```

**NAEDO TBALE**

```
customer_code    name                        start_date
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-08-01"
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-09-03"
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-08-01"
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-07-03"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-05-23"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-08-22"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-07-23"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-07-23"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-06-23"
```

**paysoft_results table**

```
custno         name                        result           result_date
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Successful"     "2014-07-05"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Tracking"       "2014-08-01"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Successful"     "2014-08-01"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Tracking"       "2014-09-03"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Successful"     "2014-09-06"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-08-25"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-06-25"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Tracking"       "2014-08-22"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-05-23"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-07-25"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Tracking"       "2014-07-23"
```

Abraham has 3 payments and 3 NAEDO records (start_date DISTINCT)
that is 3 / 3 * 100 = 100%
He is represented on the grid already (although its 99%)

Andrew has 4 payments and 4 NAEDO records (start_date DISTINCT)
that is 4 / 4 * 100 = 100%
He should be in the same place on the grid.

Maybe in the background I can collect all the grid position scores and dot the percentage calculation.

representation of one customer
[image]

Comment: The less work we have to do, the more (and better) answers you get. CREATE TABLE statements are better than descriptions of your tables; INSERT statements are better than screen shots.

Comment: Could you please give an example for desired result? SQL Fiddle with db-create scripts http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/5d52a/15